# SQL from BAT file

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a strange problem.  I am executing this from a bat file

```
cd C:\LabWorks
dbisqlc -c "DSN=Labworksdb;UID=users;PWD=labworks" select PONUMBER, orderstatus, writeback, shipdate from orderinfo, shippinginfo where orderinfo.custid = '52467' and orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid and shippinginfo.shipid > '505800'; Output to \\dp-2\ftp\Nanipics\NP_Status.csv
```

The query runs fine in my DB tool, but when I run the bat file, it changes my query, then obviously errors.  See image attached.[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You did not quote the string passed to `dbisqlc`.  Wrap the query in double-quotes.

```
dbisqlc -c "DSN=Labworksdb;UID=users;PWD=labworks" "select PONUMBER, orderstatus, writeback, shipdate from orderinfo, shippinginfo where orderinfo.custid = '52467' and orderinfo.orderid = shippinginfo.orderid and shippinginfo.shipid > '505800'; Output to \\dp-2\ftp\Nanipics\NP_Status.csv"
```

Without this, the command interpreter will think that you are redirecting output to the file "505800", then executing a new command called `Output`.

Comment: Thank you!  Now Server 2008 is killing it because of DEP.  Strangely the query works fine, it is just when I added, and shippinginfo.shipid > '505800'